# 'eb deploy' fails since yesterday, accessing to S3 fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had deployed my node.js application to Elastic Beanstalk using 'eb deploy -v' command.

It had worked well until the day before yesterday. But it started failing all of a sudden - I did not make any change on configruation. The error messages are like below:

```
INFO: Uploading archive to s3 location: CareerDay Web/app-220201_003319.zip
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done..

INFO: Creating AppVersion app-220201_003319
2022-01-31 15:33:22    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2022-01-31 15:33:27    ERROR   One or more objects in the Elastic Beanstalk bucket could not be deleted. Verify that your S3 policies allow you to perform 's3:DeleteObject'.
2022-01-31 15:33:27    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

I tried adding 's3:DeleteObject' permission to my S3 bucket but it gave me no luck. The S3 bucket is the default one created automatically when I started my Elastic Beanstalk application and there is no additional configuration I did on it.

Is there any chance you have simillar experience?

### EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

#### IAM POLICIES OF arn:aws:iam::{my-aws-account-id}:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

1. AmazonS3FullAccess

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BucketAccess",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "XRayAccess",
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
                "xray:GetSamplingRules",
                "xray:GetSamplingTargets",
                "xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CloudWatchLogsAccess",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ElasticBeanstalkHealthAccess",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:application/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

3. AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ECSAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:Poll",
                "ecs:StartTask",
                "ecs:StopTask",
                "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
                "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
                "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances",
                "ecs:Submit*",
                "ecs:DescribeTasks"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MetricsAccess",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "XRayAccess",
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
                "xray:GetSamplingRules",
                "xray:GetSamplingTargets",
                "xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "QueueAccess",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "BucketAccess",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DynamoPeriodicTasks",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*-stack-AWSEBWorkerCronLeaderRegistry*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CloudWatchLogsAccess",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ElasticBeanstalkHealthAccess",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:application/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### S3 bucket permission

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "eb-ad78f54a-f239-4c90-adda-49e5f56cb51e",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{my-aws-account-id}:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-ap-northeast-2-{my-aws-account-id}/resources/environments/logs/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "eb-af163bf3-d27b-4712-b795-d1e33e331ca4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{my-aws-account-id}:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-ap-northeast-2-{my-aws-account-id}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-ap-northeast-2-{my-aws-account-id}/resources/environments/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "eb-58950a8c-feb6-11e2-89e0-0800277d041b",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-ap-northeast-2-{my-aws-account-id}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the iAM policy?

Comment: @AllanChua Sure. The role is ```arn:aws:iam::{my-iam-number}:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role```,  and it has four policies applied. 

(1) AmazonS3FullAccess, 
(2) AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier, 
(3) AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker, 
(4) AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier.

Comment: Can you put the JSON file on the question and format it can be easier for all of us bro? BTW, where are you triggering the `eb deploy` command?

Comment: @AllanChua I added JSON texts on the question and also added s3 bucket permission too, just in case. I hope I undertood correctly.

Comment: where are you triggering the eb deploy command?

Comment: @AllanChua My mac. Logged in with my user account, and the account has AmazonS3FullAccess and AdministratorAccess.

Comment: Is the AWS account part of an AWS Organization with any SCPs denying `s3:DeleteObject` action?